# Window icon does not appear

Tags: c, debugging, raylib

As the title says, I am trying to place the window icon with raylib setWindowIcon(), but it does not appear although it loads correctly.
I have the img in the same dir as the project.
How can I know what is happening with the image, is there any way?

`Image image = LoadImage("play.png"); SetWindowIcon(image);`

`INFO: FILEIO: [play.png] File loaded successfully   INFO: IMAGE: Data loaded successfully (24x24 | R8G8B8A8 | 1 mipmaps)`

tried to use `DrawTexture(texture, x, y, WHITE);` in the Begin and End drawing field with bad results.

Comment: Could you post some [MCVE]?